# What does a "non-surrogate Unicode code point" mean in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, rust

There is a rule which says "dereferencing a raw pointer must yield a proper, non-surrogate Unicode code point" in Rust.

I do not understand what the "non-surrogate" means here. What I know is that UTF-8 has variable-length code points, so that a `Vec<u8>` cannot be converted to UTF-8 directly, and "padding" is needed.

Comment: One would assume it means a code-point that is not a [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates)

Comment: You should *never* encounter a surrogate code point in UTF-8, it's for UTF-16 only.

Comment: What page is this quote coming from? If this is talking about a raw `char` pointer, then it seems like your mention of UTF8 might just be confusing things?

Comment: page 535 and 541 of the book "Programming Rust"

Comment: No, padding is not required. The problem with converting `&[u8]` (bytes) to `&str` (UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters) is that the bytes are arbitrary and might not be correct UTF-8. Among other things this forbids surrogates. And if you use a raw pointer into the string it should follow similar restrictions, I suppose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Unicode, the code points from U+D800 to U+DFFF are called *surrogates*. They are [reserved for use by UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF), and you're not allowed to use them for anything else.

The Rust `char` type represents an abstract code point, and is not tied to any particular encoding, so storing a UTF-16 surrogate in a `char` doesn't make sense.